# Method ignoring parameter value in Ruby on Rails, using default value instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, arguments, default-value

I'm having some issues in RoR with some model methods I am setting.  I'm trying to build a method on one model, with an argument that gets supplied a default value (nil).  The ideal is that if a value is passed to the method, it will do something other than the default behavior.  Here is the setup:

I currently have four models: Market, Deal, Merchant, and BusinessType

Associations look like this:

```
class Deal
  belongs_to :market
  belongs_to :merchant
end

class Market
  has_many :deals
  has_many :merchants
end

class Merchant
  has_many :deals
  belongs_to :market
  belongs_to :business_type
end

class BusinessType
  has_many :merchants
  has_many :deals, :through => :merchants
end
```

I am trying to pull some data based on Business Type (I have greatly simplified the return, for the sake of brevity):

```
class BusinessType
  def revenue(market=nil)
    if market.nil?
      return self.deals.sum('price')
    else
      return self.deals(:conditions => ['market_id = ?',market]).sum('price')
    end
  end
end
```

So, if I do something like:

```
puts BusinessType.first.revenue
```

I get the expected result, that is the sum of the price of all deals associated with that business type.  However, when I do this:

```
puts BusinessType.first.revenue(1)
```

It still returns the sum price of all deals, NOT the sum price of all deals from market 1.  I've also tried:

```
puts BusinessType.first.revenue(market=1)
```

Also with no luck.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class BusinessType
  def revenue(market=nil)
    if market.nil?
      return self.deals.all.sum(&:price)
    else
      return self.deals.find(:all, :conditions => ['market_id = ?',market]).sum(&:price)
    end
  end
end
```

That should work for you, or at least it did for some basic testing I did first.

As I have gathered, this is because the `sum` method being called is on enumerable, not the `sum` method from `ActiveRecord` as you might have expected.

**Note:** 
I just looked a bit further, and noticed you can still use your old code with a smaller tweak than the one I noted:

```
class BusinessType
  def revenue(market=nil)
    if market.nil?
      return self.deals.sum('price')
    else
      return self.deals.sum('price', :conditions => ['market_id = ?', market])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
class BusinessType
  def revenue(market=nil)
    if market.nil?
      return self.deals.sum(:price)
    else
      return self.deals.sum(:price,:conditions => ['market_id = ?',market])
    end
  end
end
```

You can refer this link for other functions. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations